# Water simulation - How to make water spill (difference between 2.8 version and 3.6 new update)

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation, versions

How can I recreate this fluid simulation from 2.8 version to current 3.6 version? I do not see any 'obstacles' in fluid simulation.

I was following this tutorial "[making water spill from backet in blender 2 8 fluid simulation part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvEN6cnEl0k)" to create a spilling water from a glass.

While following this tutorial from 2.8, I noticed that the 3.6 version has a different setting for fluid simulation.

For example, 2.8 version had 'Obstacle' for Fluid Type. But on my current version, I only see Effector, Domain, Flow, or None

2.8 version
[image: 2.8 version - fluid obstacle]

3.6 version
[image]

From 2.8 version, aroudn 10:18, they chose:

- Fluid Type - Obstacle Settings
- Volume Initialization: Shell

[image]

If you have any suggestions for fluid, how to make the liquid stay in the shape, please let me know!!
Ideally, I would like to create a scene where a cup gets blown away by the wind and spill water.

Comment: obstacles is now called "effector". I think shell is now geometry (which means, the water is no inflow, but "one time water".

Comment: I guess there will be more tweaking necessary, because 2.8 did not use _Mantaflow_ for fluids and results might be very different in general, because it is a different simulation engine. From the 2.82 release notes when _Mantaflow_ was introduced: _"Mantaflow is the new physically-based fluid simulation framework in Blender for gas (smoke & fire) and liquid simulations. It completely replaces the existing fluid simulation systems and changes the way you work with fluids."_ If you want to work with fluids in new versions, you should watch some _Mantaflow_ tutorials instead of the old ones.